# Do a query for every loop item and wait for result

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I am making a CloudCode function that returns all users that are matching to my settings. In this function I am looping through a list of users and I need to get their settings in order to see if I should return them. The only problem is that the loop doesn't wait for the query to finish.

How can I get the Settings object for every user in the loop, check if the settings are correct and then push them in an array and return the array when the loop has finished?

The code I am using now:

```
for (var i = 0; i < connectResults.length; i++) {
    var connect = connectResults[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < matchResults.length; j++) {
        var match = matchResults[j];

        if (connect.get("sendBy").id == match.id) {
            var indexOf = matchResults.indexOf(match);
            matchResults.splice(indexOf, 1);
        } else if (connect.get("receivedBy").id == match.id) {
            var indexOf = matchResults.indexOf(match);
            matchResults.splice(indexOf, 1);
        }
        if(typeof match.get("settings") != 'undefined') {
            var settingsQuery = new Parse.Query("Settings");
            settingsQuery.equalsTo("objectId",match.get("settings").id);
            settingsQuery.find({
               success: function(setting) {
                    console.log(match.get("username") + " " + setting.get("radius"));
               } 
            });
        }
    }
}
response.success(matchResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying all users and attempting to match their settings, I would instead query all users using the setting as a query constraint. In other words, tell the database that you want it to return all the users with the right settings.

```
var usersQuery = new Parse.Query("Users");
//Below, "settings" is the column name in your Users table
usersQuery.equalTo("settings", /* Settings value you are matching */);
usersQuery.find({
  //...
});
```

You might need a `containedIn` query if there are multiple setting possibilities. See the docs for an example: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints

Good luck! :)